# Is there a limit for requests in db.sqlite3 in Django ?

Tags: django, database, sqlite

I'm working with Django and I have a db.sqlite3 database.

With my Django Website I want to add rows (Tweets collected with the Twitter API to be precised) to my database by clicking on a button.

It works but it can't add more for than 100 rows for each click on the button.

Here is the code :

```
 for tweet in tweets[:200]:
     q = Question(question_text=tweet.text, pub_date=timezone.now())
     q.save()
```

After I clicked on my button, there is 100 more rows in my database but not 200. 
So do you know if there is a limit of 100 rows by request in db.sqlite3 in Django ? And do you know how to remove that limit ?

Thank you very much by advance for your answer :)

Comment: Check the length of `tweets`. You may find it only has 100 items. Sqlite can have performance problems if you have multiple requests trying to write at the same time, but that isn't the issue here because you have a view handling a single request. Sqlite shouldn't have any problems saving 200 items sequentially in a view.

Comment: Also you might consider using bulk_create() if you want to add large amount of records to your database. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create

Comment: Thank you very much, it was indedd because of the length of "tweets", the function search() can't extract more than 100 tweets